# I want to change Gift card text how should i override this

Tags: wordpress

I want to change Gift card text how should i override this.

$label = apply_filters( 'yith_ywgc_cart_totals_gift_card_label', esc_html( __( 'Gift card:', 'yith-woocommerce-gift-cards' ) . ' ' . $code ), $code );

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `yith_ywgc_cart_totals_gift_card_label` filter to change the label/text. Please give a try to below code snippet. Hope it will resolve your issue

```
add_filter('yith_ywgc_cart_totals_gift_card_label', 'yith_ywgc_cart_totals_gift_card_label_callback', 10, 2);
function yith_ywgc_cart_totals_gift_card_label_callback($title, $code){
    $title = "Xyz";
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: WC. Please do accept answer, if you find it helpful